# failure to run a process from multiprocessing

Tags: flask, browser, pytest, multiprocess

I have been trying to run a process when testing my browser app. The process is one of my fixture for pytest testing, and it should be running when i start my test. However, it showed error when i run it. I am quite confused because it should be a simple process. this is my code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def chrome_driver(request):
    """ Selenium webdriver with options to support running in GitHub actions
    Note:
        For CI: `headless` and `disable-gpu` not commented out
        For running on your computer: `headless` and `disable-gpu` to be commented out
    """
    options = ChromeOptions()
    #options.add_argument("--headless")  # use for GitHub Actions CI
    #options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') # use for GitHub Actions CI
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_driver = Chrome(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = chrome_driver
    yield
    chrome_driver.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def run_app(app):
    """
    Fixture to run the Flask app for Selenium browser tests
    """
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")  # Needed in Python 3.8 and later
    #process = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run, args=())
    #process.start()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run, args=())
    process.start()
    process.join()
    yield process
    process.terminate()
```

above are the two fixtures for my testing, and they will be run the same time when i start my test. Below is the errors:

```
test setup failed
app = <Flask 'flask_app'>

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def run_app(app):
        """
        Fixture to run the Flask app for Selenium browser tests
        """
        multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")  # Needed in Python 3.8 and later
        #process = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run, args=())
        #process.start()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run, args=())
>       process.start()

..\conftest.py:138: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py:121: in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py:224: in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py:327: in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py:93: in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

obj = <Process name='Process-1' parent=26100 initial>
file = <_io.BufferedWriter name=11>, protocol = None

    def dump(obj, file, protocol=None):
        '''Replacement for pickle.dump() using ForkingPickler.'''
>       ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
E       AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Flask.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my similar test to run if I instead set multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork") and running the single test inside the IDE. As soon as I run it in a test suite I get the 'pickle' error though.

Comment: Troubleshooting should be left to the commend thread. If a permanent solution is found, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Henry pointed out, forking will avoid the pickle error. Set in a session scoped fixture to executed once in pytest session.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def init_multiprocessing():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")


@pytest.fixture
def run_app(app, init_multiprocessing):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=app.run)
    process.start()
    yield process
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code for testing of some multiprocessing elements in a FastAPI app.   I have added the above to my `conftest.py` but get errors like:

    assert self._popen is not None, 'can only join a started process'